# Notify function isn't updating the database while performing paypal payments

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

This is my first time integrating the Paypal Payment in a project and it is in CI. So the thing is everything is working perfectly except that the Notify Url was supposed to make me able to change the payment status from 'Pending' to 'Success' but it isn't in my case. I have the code below and i really have tried many things but still don't know where i am slipping off.

```
    <form id="paypal-pre" action="<?php echo  base_url('auth/process'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_POST['register_user_id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['customer_first_name']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['customer_last_name']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="addr1" value="<?php echo $_POST['customer_address1']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="addr2" value="<?php echo $_POST['customer_address2']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $_POST['customer_city']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="county" value="<?php echo $_POST['customer_county']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $_POST['customer_postcode']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_POST['payment_total']; ?>">
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
   </form>
```

Above is the billing info collection form.

```
function process(){
$arr['user'] = array(
    'p_user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
    'p_billing_firstname' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'p_billing_lastname' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'p_billing_address1' => $this->input->post('addr1'),
    'p_billing_address2' => $this->input->post('addr2'),
    'p_billing_city' => $this->input->post('city'),
    'p_billing_county' => $this->input->post('county'),
    'p_billing_postcode' => $this->input->post('postcode'),
    'p_status' => 'processing',
    'p_amount' => $this->input->post('amount'),
    );
$arr['pay'] = array(
    'p_amount' => $this->input->post('payment_total'),
    );
$this->load->model('demo_auth_model');
$this->demo_auth_model->process($arr);
$this->load->view('paypal',$arr);}

function notify() {
    if($this->input->post('custom') != ''){
    $id = $this->input->post('custom');
    $amt = $_POST['amount'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users_payments SET p_status='success' WHERE p_id='$id'";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    return;
}   
}
```

The Process and notify controller function

```
    <?php $paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$paypal_id = '******@yahoo.com';
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$id = mysql_insert_id();?>
<form id="paypal" action="<?= $paypal_url; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo 'Business Register'; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='<?php echo base_url('auth/notify'); ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?php echo base_url('auth/cancel'); ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?php echo base_url();?>'>
</form><script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('paypal').submit();
</script>
```

The main paypal form which is submitted automatically after saving the billing information.

```
 public function process($arr) {
        $this->db->set($arr['user']);
        $this->db->insert('user_payments');
        return;
    }
```

Process Model from demo_auth_model

Any help would be really appreciated.

P.S. All database infos are correct

Comment: i solved it anyhow.. What i did was, after i was redirected to the 'return' ur, I took the POST values from there and saved it to the table..

Answer (score 0):

well for codeigniter i prefer this library
http://tutsnare.com/integrate-paypal-using-ci-merchant-in-codeigniter/
https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant
for 2 Reasons
1. Auto redirect to our website
2. Take all data in session to our website
Try it and enjoy